# Is There a Non-Win2D Text Solution for UWP Composition API

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, win2d

To avoid an XY question, first the Y: Is there a way to create a text on a SpriteVisual that does not require Win2D?

Now the X: The problem I'm trying to solve is that I need text on a SpriteVisual (instead of a TextBlock) to apply perspective rotate 3D Expression animations on it. Text on a SpriteVisual can be done with Win2D. Here's a piece of the [Microsoft sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/composition-brushes):

```
using (var ds = CanvasComposition.CreateDrawingSession(_drawingSurface))
{
     ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
     var rect = new Rect(new Point(2, 2), (_drawingSurface.Size.ToVector2() - new Vector2(4, 4)).ToSize());
     ds.FillRoundedRectangle(rect, 15, 15, Colors.LightBlue);
     ds.DrawRoundedRectangle(rect, 15, 15, Colors.Gray, 2);
     ds.DrawText("This is a composition drawing surface", rect, Colors.Black, new CanvasTextFormat()
     {
          FontFamily = "Comic Sans MS",
          FontSize = 32,
          WordWrapping = CanvasWordWrapping.WholeWord,
          VerticalAlignment = CanvasVerticalAlignment.Center,
          HorizontalAlignment = CanvasHorizontalAlignment.Center
     }
);

_drawingBrush.Surface = _drawingSurface;

_drawingVisual = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
_drawingVisual.Brush = _drawingBrush;
```

To color text in this requires Win2D ICanvasBrush. But I want to animate the color in an Expression Animation, so I need the text color to come from a CompositionBrush. Now I could create a CompositionMaskBrush with the text brush as the mask and the CompositionBrush as the source. But with a CompositionMaskBrush I cannot add an additional mask or any other composition effects to it, which is problematic for me.

Is there an alternate approach or perhaps an enhancement to the Composition API in an Insider Build that I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y-answer: No, you can only draw text on `CompositionDrawingSurface` using Win2d `CanvasDrawingSession`. But you may get `Visual` from XAML `TextBlock` with `ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(yourTextBlock)` and animate it with Composition API expressions + XAML color storyboards.

X-answer: You can create an alpha mask from your text `CompositionDrawingSurface` and apply it to `CompositionColorBrush`:

```
    private void CreateColoredText(string text)
    {
        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
        var graphicsDevice = CanvasComposition.CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice(compositor, CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice());

        var spriteTextVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        spriteTextVisual.Size = new Vector2(512, 512);

        var maskDrawingSurface = graphicsDevice.CreateDrawingSurface(new Size(512, 512), DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, DirectXAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

        using (var ds = CanvasComposition.CreateDrawingSession(maskDrawingSurface))
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
            ds.DrawText(text, new Rect(0, 0, 512, 512), Colors.Lime, new CanvasTextFormat
            {
                FontSize = 32,
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                VerticalAlignment = CanvasVerticalAlignment.Center,
                HorizontalAlignment = CanvasHorizontalAlignment.Center,
                LineSpacing = 32
            });
        }

        var maskSurfaceBrush = compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(maskDrawingSurface);
        var surfaceTextBrush = compositor.CreateColorBrush(Colors.DeepPink);
        var maskBrush = compositor.CreateMaskBrush();
        maskBrush.Mask = maskSurfaceBrush;
        maskBrush.Source = surfaceTextBrush;

        var colorAnimation = compositor.CreateColorKeyFrameAnimation();
        colorAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0.5f, Colors.DeepSkyBlue);
        colorAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1, Colors.DeepPink);
        colorAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500);
        colorAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;

        surfaceTextBrush.StartAnimation("Color", colorAnimation);

        spriteTextVisual.Brush = maskBrush;

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(Grid, spriteTextVisual);
    }
```

Now you can animate color and perspective for your purposes.

Comment: i need to play around with that, but some possible concerns off the top of my head. Doesnt the TextBlock need to be added to the Visual Tree in order for its Visual to even work?

Comment: Can an element Visual be added to a ContainerVisual, pretty sure it can’t. The PlaneProjection animation works by applying depth transform to a ContainerVisual and then animating rotation of a child (nested Container or Sprite). Also Expressions are on Containers because there are sibling Visuals like background of the text. The new RedirectVisual might help but can’t find any docs on it.

Comment: Also regarding the CompositionMaskBrush I did mention that already and that’s what I’m doing now, but once you do that you can’t nest it in another mask or add other composition effects to it (e.g. Saturate or Hue Rotate)

Comment: Ok I was wrong the compiler does let you add an element Visual to a ContainerVisual, but I added one from a TextBlock with text in it and it does not show anything.

Comment: I've been experimenting with this. The TextBlock solution won't work. A RedirectVisual could work but the TextBlock itself has to be added to the XAML Visual Tree and it has to draw pixels no matter what. Collapsing the UIElement or setting 0 opacity (or even 0.01 opacity) makes the RedirectVisual empty. So even though you can put an element's Visual in a ContainerVisual, for all practical purposes it won't accomplish anything, and a RedirectVisual won't work unless the original is also drawn on the screen which would be a very unusual use case.